# Impossible to access object variables in promise

Tags: javascript, class, promise

I can’t seem to find a way to access an object’s variables (`this.var`) from a promise function. This is what my code looks like:

```
function myClass() {
    this.var = ‘foo’

    this.callPromise = function() {
        browser.storage.sync.get(parameters).then(this.onComplete, onError)
    }

    this.onComplete = function() {
        console.log(this.var)
    }
}

const loadClass = new myClass()
loadClass.callPromise()
```

This seems like once the function retrieves the information from the browser.storage API, it should successfully log `foo`, but instead it logs `undefined`

How can I fix this?

Comment: nothing to do with promise, to do with "callbacks" in general ... `then(() => this.onComplete(), onError)` - or even `.then(this.onComplete.bind(this), onError)`

Comment: seriously Amit? You edited the code to use 4 space indent instead of 2?